# Does monetdb support cursors?

Tags: sql, monetdb, cursors

My boss wants me to use monetdb to do some tasks.

But I've found many documents and still not sure whether the
newest version of monetdb support cursors?

if monetdb supports, could you give me an example about how to use it 
such as fetching rows, closing cursor, opening cursor and returning cursor and so on.

Comment: Why do you think you can only use it if it supports cursors? More often then not using a cursor in a relational database isn't a good idea to begin with.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name firstly,thank you for your comment,and you suggest me not to use cursor.But the document of the monetdb is so incomplete.So i can't complete my mission without using cursor,do you have some grammar documents except [link](http://www.monetdb.org) ,please mail me 199973462@qq.com.Many thx.

Comment: The unsopported features are reported here
https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/Features/unsupported

Comment: @mkersten the supported features  also include declare cursor that's why i confused.     https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/Features/Supported